# Close Vote Maths

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

Apologies if this is a repeat, I know the close vote queue has been discussed a lot but I've not actually seen these figure anywhere and just in my short time on the site the close queue has grown by over 5k.

I was musing earlier:

- 40 votes per day.
- 5 votes required to close (assuming everyone agrees), means each person effectively closes 8 questions at most.
- 104k queued.
- 13k voter days - or 35 voter years, just to clear the backlog. That doesn't even deal with the new ones coming in.

The potential number of people who could cast close votes can be seen:

- 3k reputation needed
- According to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-01-01?sort=totalreputation 17528 have 3k+ reputation (or should all the values over 3k be added up?) in which case it's around twice that.

So in theory there are enough people out there - but in reality a fair number of those people will have no interest in close votes, or will be inactive and moved on, or be too busy, etc, etc.

So the questions are:

- Does anyone know how many close voters are there? i.e. people who regularly visit the close queue and vote on more than 1 or 2 questions?
- How many new items enter the close queue each day?
- How many get closed?

I'm just trying to get a handle on the scale of the problem. :)

Comment: wait, so, if everyone over 3k visited the close queue once and did what they can, it would be gone?

Comment: Yes. If everyone over 3k used their full 40 votes they would clear the queue in one day.

Comment: Shog9 posted some information that answers part of this in [Regarding the Stack Overflow close review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208311/1288).

Comment: Wasn't queue votes more limited? I remember that limit of reviews was lower that limit of votes. Like 30 or something?

Comment: @Mołot No, you can review 40 posts in the close votes queue each day. [Here are the stats](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) for that queue.

Comment: [14,540 users with Close Vote Privileges have been active this year.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/159158/active-close-voters)

Comment: @Molot, vote limit is 50 but review limit is 40 if that's what you mean. I keep meaning to look at the "reviews today" count at midnight to see exactly how many get reviewed on average.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that every vote cast is a "close"? How do you account for "leave open"? Don't get me wrong, it's quite obvious that if *everyone* with privileges slammed it for a day or two it would be gone, but if you're trying to actually do *the math*...

Comment: Oh OK, thanks for reminding me. I'm mostly active on Drupal Answers and there is not nearly enough to use up all the votes available anyway.

Comment: @Geobits yes - that's why I said "8 questions at most" not 8 questions. However 3 open votes removes it from the queue, while 5 close votes are needed, so we can hope to a certain extent that the lower need for open votes counters out the fact they don't stack with close votes. Of course if anyone has figures on that... :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0BBq0.png - [Number of users per number of reviews](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209409/165773 "find more details here"), as of Nov 30 '13

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess, but it'd fill up again right away if participation went back to normal levels.

Comment: @djechlin I think that the number of reviewers would increase, actually, if there were a smaller number of reviews to be done. People would see that there were <20 reviews to be done, and think; hey! I can get that to zero in a few minutes!

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of psychology here. The other queues are empty so as soon as anything appears people jump on it. When you look at a queue of 100k + and see it growing every day your 40 feels a bit like emptying the sea with a bucket.

Comment: Nice to see how quickly the queue could be cleared!

Comment: @BilltheLizard http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats is really nice, is there any way to see historical stats for this instead of just a snapshot of today so far?

Comment: @TimB I don't think there is. I know they keep at least 30 days of data, but I don't know if it's available for all to see. (Do you have an Advanced Stats link on the right (below your badge progress), or is that a moderator-only link?

Comment: Moderator only I think. I see custodian reviewer ticked, steward review 539 more, then nothing under that.